# Call php script with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ubuntu, web

I developped a web application (html,php5,javascript,ajax). I was using WAMPServer on windows and it was working right. I wanted to try it on ubuntu. I've installed LAMP and I put my project in /var/www/html after giving permissions I could run it on my browser. but sending data using ajax to a php script is not working and I don't know what is the problem. Can anyone help? even this simple example is not working :

```
 <html> 
   <head> 
     <script src="/assets/jquery1.11.2.js"></script> 
   </head>
   <body> 
      <button onclick="duplicate()"/>
      <script>
        function duplicate() 
              {
                var action = "CreationBoard"; 
                var res = $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url  : "file.php",
                    data : { action : action },
                });
            res.done(function(){
                alert("success :");
            });
            res.fail(function(jqXHR , textStatus){
                alert("faild"+textStatus);
            }); 
              } 
    </script> 
</body>
```

and this is my file.php :

```
<?php 
   $res = $_POST['action']; 
   file_put_contents("result.txt",$res); 
?>
```

When the button is pressed a file named result.txt should be created, but it's not but I get a success Alert... I saw many posts about this, this is how it should be done (I think), please tell me what's wrong .. i'm not used to work with Ubuntu.
This example is working on Windows

Comment: Need to provide more troubleshooting information. Are requests being completed in network tab of browser console? If not start there for clues. Implementing ajax error handling would be a good idea. Also not sending responses from server doesn't make sense either

Comment: I didn't get what you mean!!
Can you explain more, i'm not an expert.

Comment: Then you need to study some basics about troubleshooting. We can't do your troubleshooting/debugging for you

Comment: It's working in Windows.
And the ajax code is working and it gives me a success alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install firebug and check what the response is.

what sort of permissions do you have on /var/www/html ?
Might be that you have not given it the "proper" permissions and php is not allowed to write into that specific directory.

Comment: I have 755 on /var/www/html

Comment: I had just to give 777 permissions to the Directory